# Dynamically allocated 2D array in C segm fault when rows > cols

Tags: c

I have written the following fuction to create and read a 2D array:

```
int **create_input_matrix(int *rows, int *cols) {
    printf("Number of lines: ");
    scanf("%d", rows);
    printf("Number of cols: ");
    scanf("%d", cols);
    int **matrix = (int **)calloc(*rows, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < *rows; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int *)calloc(*cols, sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("Matrix elements:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < *rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *cols; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

int main() {
   int rows, int cols;
   int **mat = create_input_matrix(&rows, &cols);
   return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault, core dumped error only when rows > cols, when they are equal or when rows < cols is works perfectly.
I really cannot understand why it breaks in that case.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking at it for at least an hour not knowing what was wrong!

Comment: int and int* are typically same size for 32-bit executables, so this appears to be 64-bit